# Array to return information in the order it was found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of mixed data, text and numbers. I have an array to return the numbers;

```
{=IF(ROW($BX$1)<=$A$1,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($BX$45:$BX$599),$BX$45:$BX$599),ROW(BX1)),"")}
```

This returns the numbers in order from smallest to largest (Small Function)

Is there a way to return the information in the order it was found?

Rather than;

```
0
2
6
8
11
```

I'd like to receive; (There is no sorting priority, the numbers correspond to a container total. I would like to receive them in the order that they are listed in Row BX45:BX599.

```
2
8
11
6
0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{=INDEX(BX:BX,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(BX45:BX599),ROW(BX45:BX599),""),ROW()))}
```

This assumes the range the formula is in starts in row 1.

If it starts in another row, use

```
{=INDEX(BX:BX,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(BX45:BX599),ROW(BX45:BX599),""),ROW()-x))}
```

where `x` = starting row number - 1